# Unable to add SDL Tridion Content Manager in MMC snap in

Tags: tridion

We are using SDL Tridion 5.3.

In MMC snap in I am trying to add "SDL Tridion Content Manager" as mentioned below

Start - Run - mmc - in cosole File - > Add remove snap in - click add - Add stand alone snap in window .

I cannot see SDL Tridion Content Manager snap in here, can anyone help me with this.

I am doing this to see/change my CMS database.  We are using SQL Server.  Is there any other way to find to which database(CMS) Conent Manager Server is pointing to ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the Tridion Content Manager Configuration tool from the start menu. Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: It was added in later versions, it's not there in 5.3

Comment: Ah indeed. I missed that version number. Wow... ancient.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on x64 system you have to type `mmc /32`, otherwise you will not see it